# How to create a NoSQL Database to find Distance between 2 locations

Tags: javascript, json, object, nosql

I want to create a Database which can hold the distance between locations. For Example Distance between New York to Boston and New York to Jersey City as well. Should I use array of objects like:

```
Distance =   {"New York":{"Boston" : 50,
                            "Jersey City": 6,
                             "Albany" : 100}, 
              "Jersey City":{"Boston" : 46,
                              "Albany" : 106,
                               "New York" : 6},
              "Albany":{"Boston" : 146,
                         "New York" : 100,
                         "Jersey City": 106}
}
```

but using the above way I will be repeating one key in each inner object.

Answer (score 1):

I would use longitude and latitude to calculate the distance between the cities. That way, you don't need to store the distances physically, and can just have an array of cities with a polygon array of longitude, latitude pairs.

For this, I use [MapBox GL's Line Distance function](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/measure/).

Comment: Thanks, Devontrae but I have data coming from an API for the distance between two zip-codes and so I am trying to store the API request into NoSQL database so that next time I don't need to call the API again if  I have the distance with me and Issue to understand the basic JSON structure which I should use to store the data. Example: I have many zip codes and distance between them but I want to store them in DB without repetition like Distance between A to B is same as B to A this is what I have also shown in my above code as well.

Comment: @BasantPatidar Ah, I understand why you would want to store this. You could cache the distance on the database, then control the caching via a model layer. Within that model layer, you can figure out if the value has been set on the corresponding city already. if so, then it can use that distance value rather than set the value again.